# Eclipse Oxygen and Google Cloud Tools Missing javax.servlet Classes from Build Path

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-plugin-eclipse

I have a GAE project in Eclipse that has been working without a problem.  I recently upgraded to the Google Cloud SDK 179.0.0 and Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) and now, when I open the project, I'm getting build path errors on classes in the javax.servlet.http package.  Specifically, the following classes are missing from my project's build path.

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
```

If you start Eclipse from the console using the following commands (assuming Eclipse is installed in your /Applications folder):

```
cd  /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
./eclipse
```

And you watch the terminal window, you'll see a bunch of stack traces similar to the following:

```
Nov 10, 2017 9:24:57 AM com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver.ServletClasspathProvider doResolveClasspathContainer
WARNING: Failed to initialize libraries
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.57
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:720)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.util.MavenUtils.resolveArtifact(MavenUtils.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.libraries.repository.MavenHelper.resolveArtifact(MavenHelper.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.libraries.repository.M2RepositoryService.resolveArtifact(M2RepositoryService.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.libraries.repository.LibraryClasspathContainerResolverService.resolveLibraryFileAttachSourceSync(LibraryClasspathContainerResolverService.java:245)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.libraries.repository.LibraryClasspathContainerResolverService.resolveLibraryAttachSourcesSync(LibraryClasspathContainerResolverService.java:106)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver.ServletClasspathProvider.doResolveClasspathContainer(ServletClasspathProvider.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver.ServletClasspathProvider.resolveClasspathContainer(ServletClasspathProvider.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.core.RuntimeClasspathProviderDelegate.resolveClasspathContainerImpl(RuntimeClasspathProviderDelegate.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.core.internal.RuntimeClasspathProviderWrapper.resolveClasspathContainerImpl(RuntimeClasspathProviderWrapper.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.core.internal.RuntimeClasspathContainer.getClasspathEntries(RuntimeClasspathContainer.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2851)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1956)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ExternalFolderChange.updateExternalFoldersIfNecessary(ExternalFolderChange.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ChangeClasspathOperation.classpathChanged(ChangeClasspathOperation.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.executeOperation(SetContainerOperation.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$10.run(JavaModelManager.java:3001)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:3017)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2038)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3497)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2687)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2851)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1956)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DynamicProjectReferences.getDependentProjects(DynamicProjectReferences.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescription.computeDynamicReferencesForProject(ProjectDescription.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescription.getAllBuildConfigReferences(ProjectDescription.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescription.getAllReferences(ProjectDescription.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.getReferencedProjects(Project.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction.buildConnectedComponents(CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction.computeRelated(CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction.getSelectedResources(CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.SelectionListenerAction.selectionIsOfType(SelectionListenerAction.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.CloseResourceAction.updateSelection(CloseResourceAction.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.selectionChanged(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.ResourceMgmtActionProvider.updateActionBars(ResourceMgmtActionProvider.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.ResourceMgmtActionProvider.fillActionBars(ResourceMgmtActionProvider.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService$3.run(NavigatorActionService.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillActionBars(NavigatorActionService.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$UpdateActionBarsJob$1.run(CommonNavigatorManager.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$UpdateActionBarsJob.runInUIThread(CommonNavigatorManager.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4033)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Contains: Missing com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.57
```

With the 179.0 version of the Google Cloud SDK installed, I now have App Engine 1.9.59 installed versus 1.9.57.

The Eclipse build path contains the following libraries:

- App Engine Standard Runtime [App Engine Standard Runtime]
- EAR Libraries
- JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]
- TestNG
- Web App Libraries

I encounter this same problem with the following Eclipse releases:

- 4.7.0 (Build Id: 20170620-1800)
- 4.7.1a (Build Id: 20171005-1200)

The following is a list of errors my project now has:

- RequestDispatcher cannot be resolved to a type
- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete.  Cannot find the class for javax.servlet.ServletContext.  Fix the build path then try building this project
- The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
- The type javax.servlet.ServletContext cannot be resolved.  It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Creating a new App Engine Standard Edition project as a Maven project specifies a dependency on the 1.9.57 version of the App Engine API.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.57</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Created issue #2754 for this problem on GitHub under the "GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse" project.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2574

---

Version Information

- Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a Build: 20171005-1200)
- Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 4.5 and later 1.4.1.201710261936
- Google Cloud SDK 179.0.0
- alpha 2017.09.15
- app-engine-java 1.9.59
- app-engine-python 1.9.62
- beta 2017.09.15
- bq 2.0.27
- core 2017.11.06
- gcd-emulator v1beta3-1.0.0
- gcloud
- gsutil 4.28
- kubectl
- pubsub-emulator 2017.09.15

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact cause of the problem, but rebooting my computer resolved the problem reported in this bug.  In the course of trying to resolve this problem, I did stop and start Eclipse several times in an effort to address the problem.  I started new terminal window sessions in an effort to fix the problem, but that didn't work.

After completely rebooting my machine, the problem reported in this bug went away.